# Simple DirectX 11 program runtime error

Tags: c++, directx

I'm new to DirectX 11, and I have managed to get the Drawing Triangle chapter in my book.
I have written this code, but I get a runtime error:
"Unhandled exception at 0x00cd14e6 in DirectX 11.exe: 0xc0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

My compiler show that the error is at the InitPipeline function, but I can't find the error there.
What have I done wrong?

Code:

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#include <d3d11.h>
#include <D3DX11.h>
#include <D3DX10.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"d3dx10.lib")

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

IDXGISwapChain                  *swapchain;
ID3D11Device                    *dev;
ID3D11DeviceContext             *devcon;

ID3D11InputLayout               *pInputLayout;
ID3D11Buffer                    *pVBuffer;
ID3D11RenderTargetView          *backbuffer;
ID3D11VertexShader              *pVS;
ID3D11PixelShader               *pPS;

// Type
struct VERTEX
{
    FLOAT X,Y,Z;
    D3DXCOLOR Color;
};
//DirectX
void InitPipeline()
{
    // load and compile the two shaders
     ID3D10Blob *VS, *PS;
     D3DX11CompileFromFile("shaders.hlsl", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
     D3DX11CompileFromFile("shaders.hlsl", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

     //debug
     if(!dev)
     {
         MessageBox(NULL, "DEV = NULL", "ERROR", NULL);
     }
     if(!devcon)
     {
         MessageBox(NULL, "DEVCON = NULL", "ERROR", NULL);
     }

     if(!VS)
     {
         MessageBox(NULL, "VS = NULL", "ERROR", NULL);
     }
     if(!PS)
     {
         MessageBox(NULL, "PS = NULL", "ERROR", NULL);
     }
     // encapsulate both shaders into shader objects
     dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS);
     dev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pPS);

     // set the shader objects
     devcon->VSSetShader(pVS, 0, 0);
     devcon->PSSetShader(pPS, 0, 0);

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0,0,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0},
        {"COLOR",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,0,D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    };

    dev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &pInputLayout);
    devcon->IASetInputLayout(pInputLayout);
}


void InitGraphics()
{
    VERTEX OurVertices[] =
    {
        {1,0,0,D3DXCOLOR(1,0,0,1)},
        {0,-1,0,D3DXCOLOR(1,0,0,1)},
        {0,0,1,D3DXCOLOR(1,0,0,1)},
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX)*3;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;

    dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pVBuffer);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
    devcon->Map(pVBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);
    memcpy(ms.pData, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));
    devcon->Unmap(pVBuffer, NULL);
}
void RenderFrame()
{
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR(0,0,1,1));

    UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
    UINT offset = 0;
    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    devcon->Draw(3,0);

    swapchain->Present(0,0);
}
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
 {
     // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
     DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

     // clear out the struct for use
     ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

     // fill the swap chain description struct
     scd.BufferCount = 1;                                   // one back buffer
     scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;    // use 32-bit color
     scd.BufferDesc.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;                   // set the back buffer width
     scd.BufferDesc.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;                 // set the back buffer height
     scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;     // how swap chain is to be used
     scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                               // the window to be used
     scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                              // how many multisamples
     scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                   // windowed/full-screen mode
     scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;    // allow full-screen switching

     // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
     if(FAILED(D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
                                   D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL,
                                   D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                   &scd,
                                   &swapchain,
                                   &dev,
                                   NULL,
                                   &devcon)))
     {
         MessageBox(NULL, "D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain Failed", "ERROR", NULL);
     }




     // get the address of the back buffer
     ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
     swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

     // use the back buffer address to create the render target
     dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backbuffer);
     pBackBuffer->Release();

     // set the render target as the back buffer
     devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, NULL);


     // Set the viewport
     D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
     ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

     viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
     viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
     viewport.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
     viewport.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

     devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    InitPipeline();
     InitGraphics();
 }
void CleanD3D()
{
    swapchain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE, NULL);
    dev->Release();
    devcon->Release();
    swapchain->Release();
    pInputLayout->Release();
    pVBuffer->Release();
    backbuffer->Release();
    pVS->Release();
    pPS->Release();
}

// Window
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    //wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = (HICON)LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = "DirectXWindow";
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        "DirectXWindow",
        "DirectX 11 (June 2010",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0,0,
        SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    InitD3D(hWnd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg = {0};

    while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

        }
        else
        {
            RenderFrame();
        }
    }
    CleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint before where it crashes and then single step the code in the debugger. Before each line, look at each of the pointers used in the next line and see if any of them are 0x00000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error basically means that you are using a null pointer somewhere. Check all your pointers. My guess is that some function somewhere is failing to set your pointers (or you have the parameters in the wrong order).

Comment: Hi! In my book, there wasn't written anything about allocation and initialization. Even on the DirectX tutorial webpage, they don't initialize them [link](http://directxtutorial.com/Tutorial11/B-A/BA5.aspx#still)

Comment: @Janman: I believe `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` is supposed to initialise them. As I said, check your pointers. That's the only way you're going to find out.

Comment: I have checked my 'D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain', and there is nothing wrong with it (I even copy pasted the 'InitD3D()' function from the webpage into my code).
Still no luck.
I find it very hard to find the error.

Comment: @Janman: Check the pointers. In `InitPipeline()` put code such as `if (!dev) std::cout << "dev is null!\n";` similarly for the other pointers. Once you figure out which one is null, then investigate why. There's no magic to debugging.

Comment: Okay, I added a "If(Failed(D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain))", and It seems nothing wrong with it.
I even added some MessageBoxes in InitPipeline(), to detect which object is NULL, and it shows me that ID3D11Blob PS and VS are NULL, but I have no Idea why, because I used the code from the tutorial I'm using.
(Code in question have been updated).

Comment: @Janman: Do you have a `shaders.hlsl` in the correct directory? I'm guessing that's the problem. Put a failed check on `D3DX11CompileFromFile` and you should find your problem.

Comment: Yes, I even tried to move it around in the directories, but I still get the problem.

Comment: @Janman: That functions returns a `HRESULT`. Find out what it is returning, it is probably an error and it will tell you what's going wrong. It could be many things.

Comment: Okay.
Thanks for the answers, I haven't solved it yet, but you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `NULL` pointer. You define 8 global D3D interface pointers and you are using `dev` and `devcon` within `InitPipeline` they need to be allocated and initialized before you can call any methods on them.

Comment: Hi!
In my book, there wasn't written anything about allocation and initialization. 
Even on the DirectX tutorial webpage, they don't initialize them [link](http://directxtutorial.com/Tutorial11/B-A/BA5.aspx#still)

Comment: The create function return an `HRESULT` you should check this to ensure it succeeded before using the devices. I don't see where in your code snippet you call any ID3D creation functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476153(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Have added an if(FAILED()), and I shows me that DeviceAndSwapChain it succeeded.
(Updated the Code in the question).

Comment: Well it was a good guess. I could make more guesses but it would be much easier for you to debug. Breakpoint, assert, log, or messagebox. Pick your poison and find out which pointer is null and when it becomes so.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1

This value tells Direct3D how much detail should be put into anti-aliasing, the higher the number the better.  Direct3D 11 video cards are guaranteed to support up to 4 here, but the minimum is 1.
Perhaps your video card doesn't support Direct3D 11?